# Can I combine result sets in Solr

Tags: solr, solrnet

I want to do the following:
Let A be the set of documents, each with the field important:true, and with a date beginning with this year, or previous year. The result set should be ordered by date. In pseudo code:

Result set A:

```
q="testquery" +important:true AND +(date:2015* OR date:2016*)
sort=date desc
```

Then, let B be the remaining set of documents, i.e. ***those with important:true and a date preceeding year 2015, and also all documents with important:false***. This set should also be ordered by date. Again in very sloppy pseudo:

Result set B:

```
q="testquery" -(date:2015* OR date:2016*)
sort=date desc
```

Now, i would like to return A followed by B, and be able to use the paging features etc. I am very noob with SOLR ( < 10 hrs of trying out different queries) and I can't figure how to accomplish this behavior. I guess I cannot use bq since we don't sort by score, right?

An example of the desired outcome:

```
<result name="response" numFound="2089" start="0">
    <doc>
        <bool name="important">true</bool>
        <str name="date">2016-03-01 00:00:00</str>
    </doc>
    <doc>
        <bool name="important">true</bool>
        <str name="date">2015-12-01 00:00:00</str>
    </doc>
    <doc>
        <bool name="important">true</bool>
        <str name="date">2015-04-01 00:00:00</str>
    </doc>
    <doc>
        <bool name="important">true</bool>
        <str name="date">2015-01-01 00:00:00</str>
    </doc>
    <doc>
        <bool name="important">false</bool>
        <str name="date">2016-10-01 00:00:00</str>
    </doc>
    <doc>
        <bool name="important">false</bool>
        <str name="date">2015-03-01 00:00:00</str>
    </doc>
    <doc>
        <bool name="important">false</bool>
        <str name="date">2014-02-01 00:00:00</str>
    </doc>
    <doc>
        <bool name="important">true</bool>
        <str name="date">2014-09-01 00:00:00</str>
    </doc>
    <doc>
        <bool name="important">false</bool>
        <str name="date">2013-05-01 00:00:00</str>
    </doc>
    <doc>

    <str name="date">2012-09-01 00:00:00</str>
    </doc>
    </result>
</response>
```

Notice in the example above that for documents older than 2015, the documents marked important is no more important than any other, they will appear in strict chronological order.

Any help is appreciated, but I would especially love examples using SolrNet syntax :)

**EDIT:**
I can not make any changes to index or schema...

Comment: Why do you have important:false, date:[2015,2016] in your docs? Seems like they should not be in either set A or B?

    <doc>
        <bool name="important">false</bool>
        <str name="date">2016-10-01 00:00:00</str>
    </doc>
    <doc>
        <bool name="important">false</bool>
        <str name="date">2015-03-01 00:00:00</str>
    </doc>

Comment: @Alexandre Rafalovitch. Maybe I wasn't clear, set B is the set of all documents matching query that doesn't already appear in set A, ordered by date desc. Set A are all documents from 2015 up until now that has the important flag set, ordered by date desc. Maybe I misunderstood your question..

Comment: Is there any reason why you would not do this client-side?

Comment: @AlexandreRafalovitch, I just realized the problem was not stated correctly. I made some clarifications (in italicized bold). I hope you have ideas for a solution if you see this :) I'm stuck

Comment: @Mico, I would really like to have the pagination feature left in Solr. It gets really messy since I would have to rewrite lots logic. If it can be done in the database, it is a oneliner, if not it is more like a 1k-liner...

Comment: Combine the queries with an OR and use boosts to order the items returned by query A first? Example: q="testquery" ((+important:true AND +(date:2015* OR date:2016*))^10000 OR (+important:false)) ? And order by score+date

Comment: @Mico, but wouldn't the "sort on date" disrespect the score? The query i have now actually returns the correct documents, but in the wrong order.

Comment: @mickey could you order by score first, then by date? You might need to add constant score for other fields (^=1.0)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120109/discussion-between-mickey-and-mico).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`((important: true AND (date:2016* OR date:2015*))^1001 OR (important: false AND (date:2016* OR date:2015*))^1000 OR date:*) AND something:"foo"` and sort `score desc, date desc`

This will show recent important items first, then recent non-important items, and finally all items, and everything sorted by date in their 'sections'.

`something:"foo"` at the end of the clause refers to any extra clauses you might have.

Comment: Sorting by date will undo any boosts you add to try moving the sections around. Those are only useful when you sort by score.

Comment: Ah yes, forgot to mention. Use sort `score desc, date desc`

Answer (score 1):

The main challenge here - I feel - is sorting by date. Without that, you could easily boost your special privilege query to be at the front. But sorting by date afterwords would reset this and you would be back where you started.

It is possible however to [sort by several fields](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Common+Query+Parameters#CommonQueryParameters-ThesortParameter). So, if your special condition could be encoded as a field value during indexing, you could sort by that first, then by date.

If that's not possible to do during the indexing, you may need to add a second trick. It is possible to [sort by a function query](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Function+Queries#FunctionQueries-SortByFunction) instead of a field. So, you would need to build a function query expression (probably using *if* and *ms* at least) that represents your boost condition.

You may have some challenges representing your 2015/2016 as a condition. If it is a date, you may be able to use [date math](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Working+with+Dates#WorkingwithDates-DateMath) to create a consistent round-down to a year (NOW/YEAR).

I would start by doing a simpler problem of just pushing the *important* item to the top, still sorted by date. Just to test that my logic here works. If/once that works with functions and sort and paging, the special dates can be added into the calculation.

Comment: Thanks! I can't change the data, and I think the date is not stored as a date object, but as a string (yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00). I had no trouble getting all the important to be put at the top and then sort the important and unimportant by date individually. I already accepted an answer that worked yesterday that used boosting, but I would really like to get something working with function query, for learning purposes if not else 